# thrust::device_vector is not updated properly

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, thrust

I am trying to save result of CUDA kernel method in device vector
below is my kernel code and data is going in to int* out and int* outTwo array when I print it.

```
template <typename T>
struct KernelArray
{
    T*  _array;
    int _size;
};
template <typename T>
KernelArray<T> convertToKernel(thrust::device_vector<T>& dVec)
{
KernelArray<T> kArray;
kArray._array = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&dVec[0]);
kArray._size = (int)dVec.size();

return kArray;
}
   __global__ void CompareVector(KernelArray<CollisionSet> inArrayA,    KernelArray<CollisionSet> inArrayB, 
 int* out,int* outTwo, unsigned int numColVec)

{
unsigned int index = __umul24(blockIdx.x, blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

if (index >= numColVec) return;
for (int i = 0; i < numColVec; i++) {

    if (inArrayA._array[index].one == inArrayB._array[i].one)
    {
        if (inArrayA._array[index].two == inArrayB._array[i].two) {
            out[index]= inArrayA._array[i].one;
            outTwo[index] = inArrayA._array[i].two; 
       printf("out %d, outTwo %d, index %d\n", out[1], outTwo[1], index);
        }
    }
}

}
```

However It is not updated to  device_vector

```
    void SweepandPrune() {

        device_vector<CollisionSet> ColVectorX, ColVectorY, ColVectorZ;
        device_vector<int> one, two;
        one.push_back(-1);
        two.push_back(-1);
        int* d_one = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&one[0]);
        int* d_two = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&two[0]);
        ColVectorX = ProjectVector(0);
        ColVectorY = ProjectVector(1);
        ColVectorZ = ProjectVector(2);

            CompareVector << <1, 256>> > (convertToKernel(ColVectorX),  convertToKernel(ColVectorY), d_one, d_two, ColVectorY.size());

}
```

this is where I launch my kernel code. when I print device_vector one's size it is still 1 (because of -1 I initilally put in)

I have searched this one
https://gist.github.com/docwhite/843f17e33e4c1f2b531a14a4bdfe90ec
and I think raw_pointer_cast should work. What did I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the answer.
the vector going into kernel need to be size specific.
So I increased size of device_vector one when I declare it.
and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic here: The Thrust vectors' sizes don't change because there is no place in the code where you're trying to change them. Other than pushing -1 into them, you do nothing which can even potentially change their size. So obviously it stays the same.